# Highcarts: Hide xAxis categorie when serie is not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have stacked column chart where I defined a serie per xAxis categorie. When I click the serie in the legend, the serie becomes hidden, which is what I want. But if the serie is not on the edge of the XAxis, the categorie remains visible. I would like to remove the xAxis label for the series that are not visible without removing them from the legend, so they can reappear when they are clicked again in the legend. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

[image: chart]

I am using `HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'`. The code to set my options is the following:

```js
    const getHighChartsSeries = (columns: string[], tsvdata: tsvdata[]) => {
        const series = [];
        for (let serie in columns) {
            const seriedata: tsvdata = tsvdata.filter((m) => m.sample_id === columns[serie])[0];
            const seriesColors = getSeriesColors(seriedata.data.map((m) => Number(m.seq_freq)));
            const data = seriedata.data.map((sd, index) => {
                return {
                    x: Number(serie),
                    y: Math.round(Number(sd.seq_freq) * 10000) / 100,
                    name: sd.clone_id,
                    color: seriesColors[index],
                };
            });
            const serieEntry: Highcharts.SeriesOptionsType = {
                name: columns[serie],
                type: 'column',
                data: data,
                color: baseColor,
            };
            series.push(serieEntry);
        }
        return series;
    };

    const setHighChartsOptions= (tsvdata: tsvdata[]) => {
        const columns = tsvdata.map((item) => item.sample_id);
        const series = getHighChartsSeries(columns, tsvdata);
        const options: Highcharts.Options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'xy',
            },
            title: {
                text: props.title,
            },
            xAxis: {
                showEmpty: false,
                categories: columns,
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage',
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}:</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.y} %<br/>',
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.name}',
                    },
                },
            },
            series: series,
            credits: {
                enabled: false,
            },
        };
        setOptions(options);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need to use `legendItemClick` to set your action.

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.events.legendItemClick

If you want to only remove `xAxis.labels`, just update them by `labels.formatter`:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: "normal",
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function () {
        let name = this.name;
        if (this.visible) {
          this.chart.update({
            xAxis: {
              labels: {
                formatter() {
                  if (this.value === name) {
                    return "";
                  } else {
                    return this.value;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          });
        } else if (!this.visible) {
          this.chart.update({
            xAxis: {
              labels: {
                formatter() {
                  return this.value;
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-gcbz2g

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

If you want to remove labels and the space left by a hidden category, you need to use the `broken-axis.js` module

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: "normal",
    grouping: false,
    pointPlacement: null,
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function () {
        if (!this.visible) {
          breaks[this.index] = {};
          this.chart.xAxis[0].update({
            breaks: breaks
          });
        } else {
          breaks[this.index] = {
            from: this.xData[0] - 0.5,
            to: this.xData[0] + 0.5,
            breakSize: 0
          };
          this.chart.xAxis[0].update({
            breaks: breaks
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-n502os?file=/demo.jsx:678-1453

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

Comment: this worked perfectly for me. Since I'm using Typescript I had change `xData[0]` to `data[0].x` but got the same result. Thnx